# Issues running event hub triggered azure function locally, getting "Out of retries creating lease for partition" error on startup

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-storage-emulator

Currently I have set up the following simple azure azure function which I tested previously few days ago and worked normally but for some unknown reason it returns an error

The function setup is:

```cs
    [FunctionName("EventUpdatedHubFunction")]
    public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger(
            "%EventConsumer:Name%",
            ConsumerGroup = "%EventConsumer:ConsumerGroup%",
            Connection = "EventConsumer:ConnectionString")]
        EventData[] events)
    {
        // logic
    }
```

And the error I am getting when I am running the function is:

```
[2022-03-04T12:25:32.671Z] The listener for function 'EventUpdatedHubFunction' was unable to start.
[2022-03-04T12:27:09.897Z] The listener for function 'EventUpdatedHubFunction' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor: Out of retries creating lease for partition 0. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The response ended prematurely, with at least 157 additional bytes expected. System.Net.Http: The response ended prematurely, with at least 157 additional bytes expected.
```

And this is my config file (which I have no reason to believe is incorrect since it has worked in the past):

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
        "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "EventConsumer:Name": "event_consumer_name_test",
        "EventConsumer:ConsumerGroup": "consumer_group_test",
        "EventConsumer:ConnectionString": "Endpoint=.........",
        "Database:ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=TestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
}
```

So far I have attempted to:

- delete and reinstall the Azure storage emulator on my machine,
- delete and recreate the azure emulator database,
- run the azure function solution on an another machine (in which case it actually worked).

**So at this point I am out of ideas of what might be causing the problem.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was: through the Azure Storage Explorer, under the `Local & Attached` find `(Emulator - Default Ports)/Blob Containers/azure-webjobs-eventhub` container and delete everything in it to free space.

Comment: I have not had this issue for ~2 years. All of the sudden, I have had the same issue twice within a week.